# How to write into CDATA without escape characters

Tags: java, xml, soap, cdata, xmlstreamwriter

We have a CDataInterceptor in order to include a signed XML file into a soap envelope in a CDATA section.

But when we are executing the code we are getting the XML escaped, like & lt;CDATA instead of <[CDATA or & #xd; when a new line. This makes the service unable to consume the SOAP envelope because of invalid format.

The issue is here:

```
public class CDataXMLStreamWriter extends DelegatingXMLStreamWriter {

private static final Pattern XML_CHARS = Pattern.compile( "[&<>]" );
private static final String CDataOpen = "<![CDATA[";
private static final String CDataClose = "]]>";

public CDataXMLStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter del) { 
    super(del);
} 

@Override 
public void writeCharacters(String text) throws XMLStreamException { 
    boolean useCData = XML_CHARS.matcher( text ).find();

    if (useCData) {
        super.writeCharacters(CDataOpen);
        super.writeCharacters(text);
        super.writeCharacters(CDataClose);
        //super.writeCData(text);
    }else { 
        super.writeCharacters(text); 
    } 
}

public void writeStartElement(String local) throws XMLStreamException { 
    super.writeStartElement(local); 
}
```

}

writeCharacters method escapes all this special characters. 
Do you know any solution to add this XML keeping escaped characters like <, > etc.?

BR

Comment: Instead of using writeCharacters in the super class , have you tried writing CDATA directly using [writeCData][1]. I see you have used it , do you get some error or other unexpected behavior ?

 if (useCData) {
        super.writeCData(text);

    }else { 
        super.writeCharacters(text); 
    } 


  [1]: https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/staxutils/DelegatingXMLStreamWriter.html#writeCData(java.lang.String)

Comment: Using writeCData includes a lot of CDATA sections in the XML file, that thing makes the service are unable to process the request... I think is making a CDATA section every new line

Comment: For example, in certificate section: <![CDATA[VPUzEfMB0GA1UE]]><![CDATA[
CwwWU0VSVklDSU9TIEVMRUNUUk9OSUNPUzEdMBsGA1UEAwwUQ29ycmVvIFVydWd1YXlvIC0gQ0Ew
HhcNMTUxMTI3MTk0NzE4WhcNMTYxMTI3MTk0NzE4WjCBmzEmMCQGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYXdml0YW1p
bmljby4wNUBnbWFpbC5jb20xEzARBgNVBAoMClZJVEFNSU5JQ08xEzARBgNVBAgMCk1vbnRldmlk
ZW8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVZMRgwFgYDVQQFEw9SVUMyMTUyMTcxOTAwMTUxIDAeBgNVBAMMF1ZJTkFM
UyBJVkFOSUNIIExFT05BUkRPMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC6LdZWhEJaqiFa
Zb1VG+o